# How to filter images and exclude filenames that include hyphen and image size in Filezilla?

Tags: regex, filter, filezilla

I have a folder in my server that contains several images resized by WordPress. I want to upload only the images that are not resized. Here's an example:

File Names :

```
2CVictoria_and_Albert_Museum_London-708x400.jpg
2CVictoria_and_Albert_Museum_London-336x190.jpg
2CVictoria_and_Albert_Museum_London.jpg
```

I want only files that end with .jpg without the -708x400 and 336x190

```
2CVictoria_and_Albert_Museum_London.jpg
```

How to create a filter in Filezilla that will ignore all the images that have been resized and show only the original image? Please if you can put all the filter rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your criteria, this should work.

```
^[[:alnum:]_]+\.jpg$
```

and after the edit requested:

```
^[[:alnum:]_-]+[^-0-9x]+\.jpg
```

and after the second edit requested:

```
^[[:alnum:]_-]+[^x]{5}\.jpg
```

I don't have Filezilla installed at the moment, but Filezilla uses POSIX regular expressions. This means we can't use lookaheads, but that shouldn't be a problem.

The expression uses a character class `[[:alnum:]_]` with a quantifier, allowing it to match any number of letters, digits and underscores. Then we match a period, jpg and the end of the string, so any suffix using a dash will fail.

In the second expression, before the `.jpg`, we make sure to match any number of characters that are not dashes, digits or xs.

In the third expression, the `[^x]{5}` is a bit of a hack: it ensures there is no "x" character in the last five characters, therefore excluding files ending in `300x225.jpg` for instance. This would also exclude some false-negatives, such as `myphotox.jpg` as well as short files such as `abc.jpg`

One way to get around the short file problem is, which accepts all four-letter filenames that don't include xs. Still a hack.

```
^[[:alnum:]_-]+[^x]{5}\.jpg|^[^x]{1,4}\.jpg
```

If there are exceptions, let me know so we can tweak the regex.

Comment: @user3001925 can you tell me what happens when you try to use the filter?

Comment: Thanks again. I think the problem is that many images have been excluded that contains a dash in the middle of the file but don't contain a dash at the end. Those should not be excluded.

Comment: So for example 2CVictoria-and-Albert-Museum-London.jpg should not be excluded

Comment: @user3001925 I thought there might be exceptions, let me take a look.

Comment: @user3001925 I have updated the answer and added this: `^[[:alnum:]_-]+[^-0-9x]\.jpg` Let me know if this one does it of if you still have edge cases.

Comment: thanks sounds better but still many files missing, I noted here some files that were excluded but shouldn't, maybe there's a rational behind:SFIFFF-SOYBABY-2012_125.jpg
FFF-SF1.jpg
Salad_IMG_1482.jpg
RootVeg_IMG_9622.jpg
Ninja_blend_Comp4.jpg

Comment: @user3001925 Have a look at the third and fourth expressions and the explanations for them.

Comment: @user3001925 Kind of a hack, but it had to be because of POSIX. Interesting question, upvoting it. Hey btw, I notice that you haven't yet voted answers up or down on StackOverflow. If this answer or any answer anywhere is helpful, please consider upvoting by clicking the up arrow on the left. Of course there is no obligation to do so. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52069/discussion-between-user3001925-and-zx81)